# Python: how to search a multi line string for specific content

Tags: python, string, find

I have created a string from

```
connectString = 'D:\Database\10.2.0\BIN\sqlplus.exe -L sys/PASSWORD'
output = str(call(connectstring))
```

this results from print output

```
stuff stuff stuff
  stuff even more stuff
ORA-28009
stuff stuff
  stuff and stuff
```

I do

```
output.find('ORA-28009')
```

but it does not find the string sequence.  The only reason I can think of is because the string is multi line.  How do I handle this?

Comment: I just typed in the literal "stuff" block, complete with newlines. output.find() worked fine. This suggests that the error is not with newlines. Please post some more details as to what exactly call(<command>) is doing, and what context you're working in.

Comment: Patrick is spot on, what you posted should work.  try including also the output of repr(call(<command>)) to see the special characters.

Comment: @Patrick Changed the code to better show what I am doing

Comment: @J.J. the output of repr(call(connectString)) is the same thing as print output but it tags a 1 at the end

Comment: @cc: What's the exact return value of your .find() call? Is there any more information you can give us? (Again, it seems like your call should work without issue).

Comment: @Patrick the return of the .find is -1.  What I am wondering is if that maybe the string isn't really a string.  If I do output=call(connectString) and try to do a .find on it it give me the error that this can't be done on an int

Comment: After looking at it more, I was getting an output from the call command, not the print output command.  print output is giving me '1'.  Which is probably the error return code

Comment: So how do I get the output of the command, not the error code return value, into my string so I can search it?

Comment: What I can do is change the call command to '<command> > test.txt' and then read that file to get my result.  But there has to be a better way

Comment: What is the output of `print map(ord, output)`?

Comment: After further testing, I have not been able to append my command to redirect the output into a txt file.  It executes the command, or at least it does not error on that line of code, but the txt file never gets created

Comment: @Adam The output of print map(ord, output) is a large sting of numbers..  [85, 115, 97, 103, 101, 58...etc...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to solve it.  The sPath variable is needed because I have two seperate instances of Oracle on the same server.  To properly test the sys account password I needed to run the sqlplus contained in the specific dir with the correct password for that instance.

```
def startSQLHelper(self, sPath, sPassword):
  print '--starting SQL helper--'
  args = [sPath + 'sqlplus.exe', '-L', 'sys/'+sPassword]
  return subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

def checkOraPass (self, sPath, sPassword):
  print '--checkOraPass--'
  p = self.startSQLHelper(sPath, sPassword)
  output = p.communicate()[0]
  print output

  if output.find('ORA-28009') != -1:
     print 'Password passed'
     return True

  return False
```

Answer (score 2):

try to normalise the string removing the special charachter.
i use a function like this:

```
def trim (str):
    str = str.replace(' ', '')
    str = str.replace('\s', '')
    str = str.replace('\t', '')
    str = str.replace('\r', '')
    str = str.replace('\n', '')
    return str
```

Maybe you can adapt it to your case.
best,
Ste

Comment: What you do is pretty much `' '.join(s.split())`

Comment: Since @cc isn't looking for a substring that contains any of these whitespace characters, they shouldn't be getting in the way of .find() Admittedly, they're superflous for what he's asking for help on, but we can't know if he might need them later (e.g. as delimiters)

Comment: right... my command would work in case you just need to chack if the string is present. but for sure does not help in locate it...

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
output = str(call(connectstring))
```

with

```
output = str(check_output(connectstring))
```

which returns the bytes from the output of the command.

Comment: This won't work for the same reason that using call(connectstring) isnt working.  The return from the command is just a 0/1 for success failure, not the actual text message that is displayed as if it was typed on the command line.  check_output(connectstring) was what I first tried and discovered this problem with